# Asynchronous/Overlapped File Read without kernel overhead?

Tags: c++, winapi, io, overlapped-io

I'm not really statisfied with the win32 ReadFile() Overlapped I/O since its really unreliable and has an unpleasent Kernel-Overhead of 8-10 milliseconds in DEBUG configuration and 25-30 milliseconds in RELEASE configuration(Visual Studio) for 400mb, the kernel overhead is proprtional to the size of bytes read... i already reported this:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Overlapping-ReadFile-takes-significantly/10475365

steps to reproduce:

1. create new Project in Visual Studio, and select Console App
2. copy paste code down below into project
3. replace “Here could be your file!!!” with a file path to a file with a size greater or equal to the READ_SIZE macro
4. run in DEBUG mode a few times to read off an average time for the overlapped read file request
5. run in RELEASE mode a few times to read off an average time for the overlapped read file request
6. compare the average time…

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

#define READ_SIZE 400000000

int main()
{
    // init
    void* data = new unsigned char[READ_SIZE];

HANDLE file = CreateFileW(L"Here could be your file!!!", // set file path to file with size of READ_SIZE 
        GENERIC_READ,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to CreateFile!\n";
        std::cin.ignore();
        return 1;
    }

// request overlapped read
    OVERLAPPED overlapped{};
    
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ReadFile(file, data, READ_SIZE, NULL, &overlapped);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to request overlapped file read\n";
        std::cin.ignore();
        return 1;
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
int readFile_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();

// wait for overlapped read to complete
    begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    DWORD bytesRead;
    GetOverlappedResult(file, &overlapped, &bytesRead, TRUE);
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

int getOverlappedResult_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();

// print results
    std::cout << readFile_duration + getOverlappedResult_duration << "(ms) for " << bytesRead / 1000000 << "(mb)\n";
    std::cout << readFile_duration << "(ms) to request overlapped file read\n";
    std::cout << getOverlappedResult_duration << "(ms) for overlapped read to complete\n";

// cleanup
    CloseHandle(file);
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

however i don't think they are going to fix this very soon, and 8 milliseconds also seems to be a lot of Kernel-Overhead too to me... what i am looking for is some way to directly tell the drivers of an SSD/HDD/M2 etc. what to do, without the kernel slowing it down.

I found that there seems to be a way using IRP's(I/O Request Package):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/handling-irps 
however in inorder to use those my code must run in kernel mode, which as far as i can tell is a very bad idea.

if you maby know wether there is a way or not for Asynchronous/Overlapped File Read without to much kernel overhead in win32 or maby some platform agnostic way, or you might be able to point me into a new direction, do so please!

Comment: If you start talking to drivers or hardware directly you'll have extra work (overhead) in your program to handle that (basically  what the kernel already does). So you'll just be moving (at least some of) the overhead to a different location (your code), but it won't make it go away - the work has to be done somewhere.

Comment: how `ReadFile` work, not depend from optimization of your code . also in linked example you by fact do synchronose read. unclear about what you asking

Comment: *i don't think they are going to fix this very soon* - here nothing to fix at all

Comment: ??? what are you talking about, 3 times more time for the same thing but in a mode where things are supposed to be faster, is something that needs to be fixed and makes me want to handle these things in my code instead

Comment: You really should post a [mre] so people can test your claims for themselves.

Comment: Overlapped I/O is the zero-overhead I/O implementation. The "non-overlapped" (synchronous) `ReadFile` implementation merely creates the kernel event object for you, issues the read followed by a `WaitForSingleObject` call, and returns when all that is done. If you are having performance issues with a specific piece of code, provide a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: well, although this question was about other ways of dooing it, i added a minimal reproducible into the question

Comment: *other ways of dooing it* - no other ways (if simply read data from file). `ReadFile` very thin shim over `ZwReadFile`. it call IoManager in kernel it it create IRP and send to filesystem. almost all work in time was in filesystem, volume and storage stack. even if you direct sent IRP from kernel to filesystem, this not change almost nothing (again if simply read data and wait after this). and all this absolute not depend from your code optimization or VS

Comment: I don't think what you are doing with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is even allowed. Have you read the [requirements for overlapped io with no buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements)?

Comment: i did, and aligment is fine ... you can very easily tell that it was executed asynchronous by running the minimal reproducible and see how long it waited and how long it needed to request asynch read... the amount of bytes to read has to be equal to a multiple of the volume sector size wich commonly is 512, if 512 is not right for some reason, ReadFile would have returned with FALSE and GetLastError would return 87(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), and my reproducible would return with: "failed to request overlapped file read" and terminate

Comment: also, if FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is not specified, everytime you repeat the benchmark, windows would just give a copy from system memory, instead of actually reading it from disk again, otherwise that would ruin the benchmark and also make ReadFile synchronous again(this is why i have it defined)

Comment: Three side notes: 1) Don't use `NULL` in modern C++, use [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr). 2) Avoid `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` - see the notes section at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock . 3) Rather than returning `1` from main as in "`return 1`" and falling off the end of `main` without returning a value, prefer to return `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` explicitly - much more portable.

Comment: "`#define READ_SIZE 400000000`" - Why a macro rather than a proper `const` or `constexpr` variable? Don't use macros when you can avoid them.

Comment: "a multiple of the volume sector size wich commonly is 512" - with many modern storage devices *4096* bytes (and for some, even 2x or 4x that) is getting more and more common, although support for 512 bytes is usually also provided even when not optimal.

Comment: @JesperJuhl *"much more portable"* - How so?

Comment: @IInspectable For example; on (Open)VMS, `1` indicates success, *not* `0`. This is handled by the `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` macros. There may be other systems that I don't know of where success/failure use weird values, but again; the standard macros handle it - an explicit `0` or `1` return from `main` does not. This bit me once and I'm sticking with the macros for my code..

Comment: @JesperJuhl The interpretation of the return value of a program is *conventional*, by its very nature. This has **nothing** to do with portability. It is dogmatism in its purest shape and adds **nothing** of value to the discussion.

Comment: @iinspectable In any case, I once wrote a program that explicitly returned `1` on failure and everything was fine until that program was compiled for VMS and shipped to a customer where suddenly that return value was interpreted as the program having succeeded and loads of things then went down hill because of that. I'll accept your comment that it's not strictly about *portability* though; it's just a good idea (IMHO).

Comment: Average time should be consistent and the same in debug or release, just surround your code in a loop you're probably seeing an effect of warmup/initialization. Not sure what problem you're after in the end.

Comment: @SimonMourier youre right it was the initalization which is not as intense in debug than in release at the the time that line of code is executed, thanks! ... however i am still curious if there are any other ways that might be faster

Comment: Overlapped I/O is the most efficient you can get from user mode. Now, before asking for a *"faster"* way, you might want to ask how to properly benchmark performance.

Comment: Use [DMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/introduction-to-adapter-objects). There is a sample, [wdm](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/general/SystemDma/wdm).

Answer (score -1):

From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements) that @Stuntman gave you:

> File access buffer addresses for read and write operations should be physical sector-aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory that are integer multiples of the volume's physical sector size.

I don't think you're doing that (and the alignment you *are* getting might vary between Debug and Release builds).

> Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.

So again, given the above, there might be a secondary effect (i.e. buffer alignment) which is affecting your timings.

**But** see @rbmm's comment below.  You still have an alignment issue, just not the one I thought you had.

Comment: `operator new` returns a pointer that is suitably aligned for **any** type.

Comment: documentation containg error. in case not buffered io - size of buffer and file offset, must be sector size aligned. but *buffer addresses* - no. it must be aligned, but not for sector size. but on [`AlignmentRequirement` + 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_alignment_information).

Comment: @rbmm I see.  OP take note, because you are not doing this.  Answer left live so as to not lose rbmm's comment.

Comment: @IInspectable Not in this case it doesn't.

Comment: correct information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatefile): *1. Any optional ByteOffset passed to ZwReadFile or ZwWriteFile must be a multiple of the sector size.* *2.The Length passed to ZwReadFile or ZwWriteFile must be an integral of the sector size.* *3. Buffers must be aligned in accordance with the alignment requirement of the underlying device.*

Comment: @rbmm thank you very much.  This just *has* to be your problem, OP